# NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#ne

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've multiple devise models
I've overridden the registrations controller in devise and it works just fine. But when i try to sign in, i get this error.

undefined method `sanitize' for 
nil:NilClass
Edit : This code belongs to devise*

```
def sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_in)
  end
```

def serialize_options(resource)

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
def sign_in_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in)
end
```